# Am I using the wrong way to get the values of input fields in react.js

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, components, jsx

I have some question in react please see the image from the link below and tell me is code is right or wrong

```
const Form = () => {
  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].value);
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('input')[1].value);
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('input')[2].value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>This is Form</h1>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your name" name="name"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your E-mail" name="email"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your Mobile" name="mobile"
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F6bt.png

Comment: please typeout your code instead of using images. And yes, you should avoid using raw javascript queries in react.

Comment: We can't help debug or diagnose code we can't see. Please edit your post to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the relevant code you have an issue working with. To answer your question, use either React state to store the field values or use the form's `onSubmit` event object to access the field values. Using state is the preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't query the DOM directly in React if you can help it. It's generally considered an anti-pattern. Other methods exist to access underlying DOMNodes in React, namely React refs. For the specific case of working with forms and form data it's generally considered best practice to use local component state and controlled inputs.

Example:

```
const Form = () => {
  const [formState, setFormState] = React.State({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    mobile: '',
  });

  const changeHandler = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormState(state => ({
      ...state,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formState);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>This is Form</h1>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your name" name="name"
          value={formState.name}
          onChange={changeHandler}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your E-mail" name="email"
          value={formState.email}
          onChange={changeHandler}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your Mobile" name="mobile"
          value={formState.mobile}
          onChange={changeHandler}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

You can also access the form field values via the `form` element's `onSubmit` event object.

Example:

```
const Form = () => {
  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = e.target.name.value;
    const email = e.target.email.value;
    const mobile = e.target.mobile.value;
    console.log({ name, email, mobile });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>This is Form</h1>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your name" name="name"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your E-mail" name="email"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your Mobile" name="mobile"
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```